# Images don't load on button. Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image

I made a button with the class WWZButton but the class does not work apparently. i want to add a image what is '**arrow_btn**'

This is how it looks now. But there needs to become the arrow_btn on the right side. [Login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnLiB.png)

this is the class code: `import UIKit

class WWZButton: UIButton {

```
@IBInspectable var isOrange: Bool = true

private var rightImageView: UIImageView?

func setupView() {

    rightImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
    rightImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width - 35, y: 7.5, width: 25, height: 15), image: UIImage(named: "arrow_btn")!)
    rightImageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    addSubview(rightImageView!)
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    Utilities.createBorder(forView: self, color: UIColor.clearColor(), width: 0, radius: 8)
    if isOrange == true {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeButtonColor()
    } else {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.grayButtonColor()
    }
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                              attribute: .Height,
                                              relatedBy: .Equal,
                                              toItem: nil,
                                              attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: 30)
    self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupView()
}
```

}

[Screenshot of button class + isOrange set true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4uZe.png)

Why is it not working? The code is good?

Answer (score 0):

This works with me

```
class WWZButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var isOrange: Bool = true

    private var rightImageView: UIImageView?

    func setupView() {

        rightImageView?.removeFromSuperview()

        rightImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        rightImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width - 35, y: 7.5, width: 40, height: 40))

        rightImageView?.image =  UIImage.init(named: "car1.png")

        rightImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        addSubview(rightImageView!)
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        if isOrange == true {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                                  attribute: .height,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: nil,
                                                  attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 100)
        self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Still didn't work. Is something else not working than?

Comment: All of my images in the whole project doesn't show correctly?

Comment: Did you set top , leading / trailing for the button ? add .png extension , verify all of them copied to the project folder